# Heterogenous collection of CRTP-based polymorphic elements

Tags: c++, collections, polymorphism, c++17, crtp

Let us admit that, for any valid reason, dynamic (virtual) polymorphism is not available to us. CRTP provides efficient static polymorphism that looks like what follows :

```
template<typename derived_t>
struct Base {
    void sayFoo() { std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
    void sayBaz() { std::cout << impl().bazWord() << std::endl; } 
        
    derived_t& impl() { return static_cast<derived_t&>(*this); }
   
};

struct derived1 : public Base<derived1> {
    std::string bazWord() { return "baz1"; }
};

struct derived2 : public Base<derived2> {
    std::string bazWord() { return "baz2"; }
};
```

Instanciation is easily done like so :

```
derived1 d1;
d1.sayFoo(); // says "foo"
d1.sayBaz(); // says "baz1"

derived2 d2;
d1.sayFoo(); // says "foo"
d2.sayBaz(); // says "baz2"
```

Now, I would like hold those elements in a heterogenous collection, which would looks like this :

```
std::vector<Base<??>> v;
v.push_back(d1);
v.push_back(d2);
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto& elem) { elem.sayBaz(); })
```

Doing this gets me an error, obviously because the base type cannot be defined.

**Is there a simple way to achieve a CRTP-based heterogenous collection ?**

Comment: You can use `runtime-concept` idiom, which doesn't need run-time polymorphism at the interface level, but still you need to have runtime polymorphism at implementation level. https://youtu.be/QGcVXgEVMJg link will provide you good information about the mechanism by Sean Parent.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (but probably not the most elegant) is using `std::tuple`. The following example works well :

```
auto coll = std::make_tuple(d1, d2);
std::apply([&](auto & ... el) { 
    (..., el.sayBaz());
}, coll);
```

Iteration is not straight-forward and it comes with all the advantages and disadvantages of `std::tuple` (mainly, no runtime insertion), but at least it works !